# Compiling linux module dtoped, and returns No cuch file or directory? Make file cann't find /lib/modules/<version>/build

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I wrote a Hello-world module, and built Make file to compile it.

Makefile source code:

```
obj-m +=hello-1.o
all:
       make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
       make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

compiling the module by issuing the command make give me the following result

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.3.4-5.fc17.i686/build M=/home/user/MyModules/hello-1 modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.3.4-5.fc17.i686/build: No such file or directory. Stoped.
make: *** [all] Error 2
enter code here
```

While the file is actually Exist!

Why Makefile can't find the file?

- Note: I'm using fedora 17

Comment: Yes, I have.
I installed it

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /lib/modules/3.3.4-5.fc17.i686/build/`?